# SELECT column WHERE (type = 'S' OR type = 'B') but perform different actions depending on whether type = 'S' or 'B'

Tags: postgresql, select

))Hi all, currently Im stuck in an issue, hope some good PostgreSQL fellow programmer could give me a hand with it. This is my table...

[image]

I only want to select **one** "time" row, **either** WHERE "time_type" = 'Start' OR "time_type" = 'Break', **but only one**, the one that is at the bottom row (descending) (ORDER BY "fn_serial" DESC LIMIT 1).

Im successfully doing it by using this Trigger Function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timediff()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
prevtime character varying;

BEGIN
SELECT t.time FROM table_ebscb_spa_log04 t WHERE t.fn_name = NEW.fn_name AND (t.time_type = 'Start' OR time_type = 'Break') ORDER BY t.fn_serial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO prevtime;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'NOT FOUNDED';
  ELSE
    NEW.time_elapse := prevtime
  END IF;
return NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION timediff()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

But in my script I would like to perform different actions depending on whether "fn_type" = 'Start' OR "fn_type = 'Break', I mean where "prevtime" variable came from, eg:

```
IF "prevtime" came from "fn_type" = 'Start' THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'PREVTIME CAME FROM START';
ELSIF "prevtime" came from "fn_type" = 'BREAK' THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'PREVTIME CAME FROM BREAK';
```

I can hardly imagine a way to do that, so I would like to ask for suggestions.

I guess one way to achieve this could be, create a sub IF, to check which one ('Start' OR 'Break') is at the bottom row (descending). How could I do that? or what could be a better approach?

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: That's a function not a trigger.

Comment: oh, yes sorry, postgresql calls it Trigger Function, thanks. <edited> any idea please???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use more than one variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timediff()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
prevtime character varying;
time_type character varying;

BEGIN
SELECT t.time, t.time_type FROM table_ebscb_spa_log04 t WHERE t.fn_name = NEW.fn_name AND (t.time_type = 'Start' OR time_type = 'Break') ORDER BY t.fn_serial DESC LIMIT 1    INTO prevtime,time_type;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'NOT FOUND';
ELSE
NEW.time_elapse := prevtime;
RAISE NOTICE "THE TIME CAME FROM %", time_type;
END IF;
return NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION timediff()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas Garman, thanks, your answer rouse a kinda sub-question, please could you give me a hint? Thanks Advanced. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091495/select-column-where-time-type-break-but-only-the-rows-that-are-belowinserte

Comment: Yes I put an answer over there.